# Count and remove duplicates in jq

Tags: json, jq

I have an array of objects and I want to remove some duplicates in this array, I want to keep the count of the duplicates though.

My input is:

```
[
    {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": "a",
        "baz": "whatever"
    },
    {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": "a",
        "baz": "hello"
    },
    {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": "b",
        "baz": "world"
    }
]
```

(not sure if it's important but the uniqueness of an object is based on `foo` and `bar`, not `baz`.

An example of desired output would then be:

```
[
    {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": "a",
        "baz": "whatever",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": "b",
        "baz": "world",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

or even:

```
[
    {
        "count": 2,
        "data": {
            "foo": 1,
            "bar": "a",
            "baz": "whatever"
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

I know how to do the uniqueness part (with `unique_by([.foo, .bar])`) but not the counting part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following command based on `group_by`:

```
group_by(.foo,.bar)
| map(.[]+{"count":length})
| unique_by(.foo,.bar)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": "a",
    "baz": "whatever",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": "b",
    "baz": "world",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

The other output you mentioned can be achieved with this command:

```
group_by(.foo,.bar)
| map({"count":length,"data":(unique_by(.foo,.bar)[])})
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "count": 2,
    "data": {
      "foo": 1,
      "bar": "a",
      "baz": "whatever"
    }
  },
  {
    "count": 1,
    "data": {
      "foo": 1,
      "bar": "b",
      "baz": "world"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, It works! For the second output, wouldn't it be simpler to do `"data": first` ?

Comment: Yeah, can be used too. And would be simpler!

Comment: Oh yes! Removed.

Comment: There's no need for unique_by in either answer, e.g. for the first approach, the following is enough: group_by(.foo,.bar) | map(.[0]+{count:length}). For the second:  group_by(.foo,.bar) | map({"count":length,"data": .[0]})

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which uses [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak)'s [GROUPS_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45715729/8379597) instead of [group_by/1](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#group_by(path_expression)) to avoid sorting:

```
def GROUPS_BY(stream; f): reduce stream as $x ({}; .[$x|f] += [$x] ) | .[] ;

  GROUPS_BY(.[]; {foo,bar}|tostring)
| .[0].count = length
| .[0]
```