# How can I process oneline json files using `jq`

Tags: json, command-line, jq, data-processing

I have a onelined json file that looks similar to this

```
{"fieldA":1, "fieldB":"foo"}
{"fieldA":2, "fieldB":"bar"}
{"fieldA":4, "fieldB":"foobar"}
...
```

How can I properly read this file using `jq`?

I tried doing:

```
cat myFile.json | jq [.]
```

but this returns something like:

```
[{
  "fieldA":1, 
  "fieldB":"foo"
}]
[{
  "fieldA":2, 
  "fieldB":"bar"
}]
[{
  "fieldA":4, 
  "fieldB":"foobar"
}]
...
```

but I would like to receive this instead:

```
[{
  "fieldA":1, 
  "fieldB":"foo"
},
{
  "fieldA":2, 
  "fieldB":"bar"
},
{
  "fieldA":4, 
  "fieldB":"foobar"
},
...]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can slurp the input file with `-s`: https://jqplay.org/s/uFL1SucU6v

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine the sequence of objects in jq into one object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477547/how-to-combine-the-sequence-of-objects-in-jq-into-one-object)

Comment: Despite asking about "object" in the title, the question also asks about (and gets an answer for) combining into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *sure* you want that? What's your end goal? You can merge all of the inputs into a single array using `jq -n '[inputs]'` (the `-n` avoids the usual reading of stdin into `.`, allowing it all to appear on `inputs`), but that means that it can't produce any output, or do any further processing, until the entire input has been read, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: [it can't produce any output, or do any further processing, until the entire input has been read] is this when using `inputs` or `.`?