# join individual key:value maps into a single map using jq

Tags: jq

Hi I have below code which has individual `key:value` maps needs to be merged into a single `key:value` map

From below code

```
{
    "Key1": "value1",
    "Key2": "value2",
    "Key3": "value3",
    "Key4": "value4"
}
{
    "Key1": "value1",
    "Key2": "value2",
    "Key3": "value3",
    "Key4": "value4"
}
```

To below code using `jq`

```
{
    "Key1": "value1",
    "Key2": "value2",
    "Key3": "value3",
    "Key4": "value4"
},
{
    "Key1": "value1",
    "Key2": "value2",
    "Key3": "value3",
    "Key4": "value4"
}
```

Comment: Both `from` and `to` are exactly the same? If you [edit] your question to fix that, please add your attempts.

Comment: Adding a comma renders it invalid JSON. That seems unwise.  Did you mean you want to convert the input stream into a single JSON array?

Comment: yes, convert individual key:value maps into a single JSON array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine the sequence of objects in jq into one object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477547/how-to-combine-the-sequence-of-objects-in-jq-into-one-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find the dupe, so here goes.

To add each file as element into one big array, you can use [`-s`/`--slurp`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) with the [identity filter `.`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Identity:.):

```
jq -s '.' file1.json file2.json
```

… or collect [`inputs`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#inputs) into [an array](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Arrayconstruction:%5B%5D) (with `-n`/`--null-input`):

```
jq -n '[inputs]' file1.json file2.json
```

or without `-n`:

```
jq '[., inputs]' file1.json file2.json
```

You can read more about the differences of slurping vs consuming inputs in [Difference between slurp, null input, and inputs filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73843868/difference-between-slurp-null-input-and-inputs-filter)

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Key1": "value1",
    "Key2": "value2",
    "Key3": "value3",
    "Key4": "value4"
  },
  {
    "Key1": "value1",
    "Key2": "value2",
    "Key3": "value3",
    "Key4": "value4"
  }
]
```