# Why doesn't the jq filter 'exp as $var | .' print the original input as documented?

Tags: json, bash, command-line-interface, jq

[jq's documentation](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#variable-symbolic-binding-operator) says (emphasis mine):

> The expression `exp as $x | ...` means: for each value of expression `exp`, **run the rest of the pipeline with the entire original input**, and with `$x` set to that value.

Here's my own interpretation: in `exp as $x | ...`, the `...`'s context starts at the original input to the `jq` command. If that's the case, why doesn't `exp as $x | .` print the original input? Here's my example ([playground link](https://jqplay.org/s/X8sJ_U9KGmU)):

Filter: `(.signal[] | select(.name | contains("signal"))) as $matches | .`

Input:

```json
{
  "noise1": 5,
  "signal": [
    {
      "name": "child-signal-1",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-noise-2",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-signal-3",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "noise2": [
    {
      "name": "child-signal-1",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-noise-2",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-signal-3",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "noise1": 5,
  "signal": [
    {
      "name": "child-signal-1",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-noise-2",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-signal-3",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "noise2": [
    {
      "name": "child-signal-1",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-noise-2",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-signal-3",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
{
  "noise1": 5,
  "signal": [
    {
      "name": "child-signal-1",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-noise-2",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-signal-3",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "noise2": [
    {
      "name": "child-signal-1",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-noise-2",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-signal-3",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd also like to understand why my output prints the input twice, thereby making it invalid json. I think that relates to `(.signal[] | select(.name | contains("signal")))` returning 2 results, but I don't understand how that's relevant if I'm not referencing the variable on the RHS.

Comment: You do get the original input but you created multiple instances of it. For each one of them, `$matches` is bound to exactly one of the evaluation results of the expression before `as`.

Comment: @pmf Okay but I'm not referring to `$matches` anywhere, so why does that matter? Also if I remove the outer parentheses around the left-hand side, it doesn't print the *original* input either: https://jqplay.org/s/4iJKKqEMYOg I believe that's because this is the resulting order of operations: https://jqplay.org/s/zVnovnxYyl9 But for that to explain why the behavior works the way it does, I have to ignore the term "original" in the phrase "original input." Is the documentation wrong in using that phrase?

Comment: Without the parens, you iterated over the items of the `.signal` array, making each instance having one of the items its current context, and then bound `$matches` to whatever `select` evaluated to. The latter produced one instance for each of the two outer instances, leaving you with two instances overall.

Comment: @pmf Thanks. That confirms my intuition, but I still don't see how the term "original input" is correct in the documentation. Wouldn't "whatever was bound before `exp`" be more accurate?

Comment: Read "input" as one JSON entity, not as contents of an input file. The creation or elimination of instances happens based on these entities. Each filter takes exactly one input, and produces an arbitrary number of it (zero or more). With more than one input, the filter is accordingly run mutiple times. Thus, the jq process can have multiple inputs (regardless of the number of input files processed), and multiple outputs. This multiplicity in jq's terminology is called a "stream".

Comment: In other words: Given a pipeline `a | b`, the outputs of `a` become the input of `b`. But with `a | exp as $x | b`, `b` runs with `$x` bound to the result(s) of evaluating `exp`, its input, however, is the "original" input, i.e. the one that `exp` had, namely the outputs of `a`.

Comment: Sounds like you got a resolution. I'm inclined to vote to close, because I'm not sure the question is answerable in its current form - you asked why does it not output the original input, and why does it do this twice, but the example given _does_ output the input, twice, so I'd say the first and main part of the question is unreproducible without clarification of what wasn't as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler example:

```bash
printf '%s\n' '[ "abc", "def" ]' | jq -c '.[] as $x | .'
```

```json
["abc","def"]
["abc","def"]
```

We could also write this as follows:

```bash
printf '%s\n' '[ "abc", "def" ]' | jq -rc '.[] as $x | ". is " + tojson'
```

```json
. is ["abc","def"]
. is ["abc","def"]
```

You say `.` isn't producing the original input, but we clearly see it is in this latest snippet.

What you're really actually asking about is why the expression that follows the `|` is evaluated multiple times. This results from the use of `.[]`.

> If you use the `.[index]` syntax, but omit the index entirely, it will return *all* of the elements of an array. Running `.[]` with the input `[1,2,3]` will produce the numbers as three separate results, rather than as a single array. A filter of the form `.foo[]` is equivalent to `.foo | .[]`.

When something produces multiple values, the rest of the pipeline is evaluated for each of those values.<sup>[1]</sup>

> Some filters produce multiple results, for instance there's one that produces all the elements of its input array. Piping that filter into a second runs the second filter for each element of the array. Generally, things that would be done with loops and iteration in other languages are just done by gluing filters together in jq.

This is repeated in `as`'s documentation.

> The expression `exp as $x | ...` means: for each value of expression `exp`, run the rest of the pipeline with the entire original input, and with `$x` set to that value. Thus `as` functions as something of a foreach loop.

Let's look at a slightly more elaborate version of my original version:

```bash
printf '%s\n' '[ "abc", "def" ]' | jq -c '.[] as $x | [ ., $x ]'
```

```json
[["abc","def"],"abc"]
[["abc","def"],"def"]
```

The documentation I've quoted says this should be equivalent to the following:

```bash
printf '%s\n' '[ "abc", "def" ]' | jq -c '
   . as $orig |  # Save original input.
   .[] |         # Produces multiple values.
   .  as $x |    # This is evaluated for each of those values.
   $orig |       # Set `.` to the original input.
   [ ., $x ]
'
```

```json
[["abc","def"],"abc"]
[["abc","def"],"def"]
```

---

1. And when something produces no values, the rest of the pipeline isn't evaluated.

Comment: It might help to describe what a [here-string (`<<<`)](https://askubuntu.com/a/678919/1297632) does because, in my experience, it's a rare operator.

Comment: Fine, replaced  it with `printf`.

Comment: Apologies if that came off as nitpicking and difficult. I didn't mean it that way.

Comment: No worries. I'm a huge nitpicker. You had a point when you said it was rare. To be precise, it's not something the POSIX shell supports. It's something bash supports.

Comment: Is that `". is "` in your second example piping a filter to a string or another concept? I want to RTFM, but I wouldn't know where to start with that one.

Comment: It's piping to `". is " + tojson`. It's piping to a concatenation. The things being concatenated is the string `. is ` and the JSON serialization of `.`. This compares to `4 | 5 + .`. The value four is pass to the addition (of 5 plus the value passed).

Comment: `When something produces multiple values, the rest of the pipeline is evaluated for each of those values.` For others, [`jq`'s "slurp" concept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34477713/61624) is how to <s>do the opposite, merging multiple into one</s> merge multiple objects into an array.

Comment: Kinda. Slurping applies only to the original input, whereas the part you quoted applies to each segment of the pipeline. Slurp is a specific case of wrapping an expression with `[ ... ]`.