# Using jq, how do I conditionally modify a portion of its input and output the original structure with those changes?

Tags: json, bash, command-line, jq

I have an `input.json` file with this content:

```json
{
  "noise1": 5,
  "signal": [
    {
      "name": "child-signal-1",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-noise-2",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-signal-3",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "noise2": [
    {
      "name": "child-signal-1",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-noise-2",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-signal-3",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Using `jq`, I want to read in that file and output this:

```json
{
  "noise1": 5,
  "signal": [
    {
      "name": "child-signal-1",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "CHANGED-1"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-noise-2",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-signal-3",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "CHANGED-3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "noise2": [
    {
      "name": "child-signal-1",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-noise-2",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child-signal-3",
      "nested": {
        "prop": "child-prop-3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's the change in words: `.signal[]` objects with a `.name` that contains "signal" should set their `.nested.prop` value to `"CHANGED-"` plus the aforementioned `.name`'s last digit. The result should be the original json with this modification.

---

I've somehow stumbled upon [the answer](https://jqplay.org/s/TilSRhvCWW6), but I don't fully understand why it works, especially when compared to everything I tried previously (see #2 below):

```
.signal[] |= (select(.name | contains("signal")) .nested.prop = (.name | gsub(".*-(?<namedigit>[0-9])"; "CHANGED-\(.namedigit)")))
```

1. Is there a simpler way to write the above?
2. Why did all my other attempts print multiple json objects:

   ```
   .signal[] | select(.name | contains("signal")) as $matches | .
   (.signal[] | select(.name | contains("signal"))) as $matches | .
   .signal[] | select(.name | contains("signal")) | .nested.prop = (.name | gsub(".*-(?<namedigit>[0-9])"; "CHANGED-\(.namedigit)"))
   ```

   To be clear: I'm not asking for a detailed explanation of each, I just assume they share a common theme that causes multiple json outputs, and I'd like to understand what that is.

Comment: For 2) doesn't this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77924756/why-doesnt-the-jq-filter-exp-as-var-print-the-original-input-as-document#comment137377901_77924756) on your previous question make sense?

Comment: Re "I want to read in that file and output this": Showing the expected output is good, but please also describe in words what motivates the changes. We can see that two fields get `CHANGED` but it's not obvious why and why these fields. Thank you.

Comment: @Inian Good point. Because of your comment I suppose what I'm really confused about in 2) is what `|=` does in the working example, and why replacing `|=` with `=` gives this error: `null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string`. I've read the official docs about these topics repeatedly, but I guess I'm not getting it.

Comment: @pmf I don't know if this is what you're looking for but my motivation is I have a real file with a similar structure that I want to modify in a similar way.

Comment: @Daniel No, in order to make people understand your task and help you find answers to your questions, you need to describe them the actual process you're dealing with, rather than having them search for and reason about the modified pieces for themselves. In this case, this could be something along the lines of: "For every item in the `.signal` array whose `.name` value contains the substring `"signal"`, I want to change the value of `.prop` by replacing the part before the digit to `"CHANGED"`. Here's my expected output for the sample input given."

Comment: @Daniel As a matter of fact, I just realized that the new values aren't constructed by just "replacing the part before the digit to `"CHANGED"`", they're also having the digit itself replaced with the one contained in the respective `.name` value. This very much exemplifies why it is so crucial that you be the one providing this information.

Comment: @pmf Sorry, when you said the word "motivates" it confused me as to what you are asking. I didn't realize the differences between the two versions were difficult to spot, but you have described the difference between the two.

Comment: @pmf I have edited my answer to include this information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there a simpler way to write the above?

Here's my alternative approach. It updates every item in the `.signal` array by providing a new value to `.nested.prop` under the condition that the value of `.name` contains a given substring. The new value itself is a concatenation of a literal part and the final digit from that `.name` value. If the condition is not met, the original value is kept implicitly. (Versions of jq prior to 1.7 needed to spell out `else .` explicitly.)

```bash
.signal[] |= if .name | contains("signal") then
  .nested.prop = "CHANGED-\(.name | scan("\\d$"))"
end
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/12Ln25Z5by4)

---

> 2. Why did all my other attempts print multiple json objects:
>
> ```
> .signal[]
> | select(.name | contains("signal")) as $matches
> | .
> ```

`.signal[]` has three outputs (each being an object of the form `{"name":…, "nested":…}`). `select` then filters out one of them (as it doesn't match the provided condition), and `as` binds the remaining two to a variable. Finally, `.` unconditionally produces both. Note that no traversal was performed with the binding, so the context produced by `.` is identical to the value bound to the variable (in both cases).

> ```
> (.signal[] | select(.name | contains("signal"))) as $matches
> | .
> ```

Here, the whole parenthesis became the expression for the binding, which, as shown in the previous snippet, evaluates to two objects of the form `{"name":…, "nested":…}`. These are still the values bound to the variable, but as the traversal (`.signal[]`) now occurs inside the binding expression, the "original" context, i.e. [the one from before the binding expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77924756/why-doesnt-the-jq-filter-exp-as-var-print-the-original-input-as-document#comment137377901_77924756), here being the overall input provided to jq (`{"noise1": 5, "signal": […]}`), is the one produced (twice) by the final `.`, each with one of the bindings accessible in the variable.

> ```
> .signal[]
> | select(.name | contains("signal"))
> | .nested.prop = (
>     .name
>     | gsub(".*-(?<namedigit>[0-9])"; "CHANGED-\(.namedigit)")
>   )
> ```

This attempt suffers from the impossibility to backtrack from a traversal while being inside the traversing context. Compare how in the previous snippet the traversal only affected the context for the filters inside the parentheses, while the "original" context was "saved" for the filter following it. Likewise in this snippet, `.nested.prop = (…)` sets a value which is evaluated by traversing into `.name`, which becomes the context for `gsub`, but the context after the assignment (which also happens to be the final context) is still the one `.nested.prop` was valid in. But as you start out with `.signal[] | …` you leave the top-level context without being able to return.

There are generally two ways to make returning possible. One is to use variables to store a context that would otherwise be unreachably left behind. For example, if you continued your first snippet by further traversing down, you'd see how you can still access the saved context (which wasn't the top level context, though) by reading the variable. You could even make it a new context by having `$matches` as a filter by itself. But variables are immutable (as in most FP paradigms), so you can only read from them, and restoring a context this way would simply just expunge any previous context that you may have carefully transformed on your way there.

The other way would be to only traverse within parentheses, which is what the solution you "stumbled upon" is doing: `.signal[] |= (…)`. The (update-)assignment is performed on top level, while all traversal happens inside parentheses (which by themselves may again contain other assignments and traversals). Note that the LHS traversals in `.signal[]` and `.nested.prop` are just shorthands for `(.signal | .[])` and `(.nested | .prop)`, respectively. This is generally the way how to produce a higher level context with modifications on a deeper level.

Comment: The extensive explanation elevates this answer from good to great. One of the hardest things for me in learning jq is to develop a mental model of what is going on, and this answer really helps me. Thank you.